# Upgrading "default" Java JRE 11

Tags: java

My Elementary came with JRE 11 by default. After installing IntelliJ I write a code in Java 14 (I like those fancy new Switch statements...) but running my .jar files will end with

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class senestudio.Main
  java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: senestudio/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
```

message.

So, my question is: how do I upgrade my Elementary JRE to version 14 (or higher, if applicable) without breaking anything, as I'm still relatively new to the Linux world.